# Vue Router not working - defaulting to the root path

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have 2 code's. one works and one doesn't, i would like to know one is not working

This one is written using JS ( and this work as usual)

```
import Alice from "@/Alice.vue";
import Bob from "@/Bob.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Alice",
    component: Alice,
  },
  {
    path: "/bob",
    name: "Bob",
    component: Bob,
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

Whereas this one written in TS doesn't work( the path is defaults to always to the root path ie: "/", when i try to navigate to /bob, router path is still "/"(i checked this using vue devtools), and ofcourse it doesnt show what i want, it still shows Alice insted of Bob).

```
const Alice = () => import("./Alice.vue")
const Bob = () => import("./Bob.vue")

export default createRouter({
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            name: "Alice",
            path: "/",
            component: Alice
        },
        {
            name: "Bob",
            path: "/bob",
            component: Bob
        }
    ]
})
```

i wonder what is the problem

Router is rendering, but only the root path. Everything else router defaults to "/" path

Comment: Can you use createWebHistory instead of createWebHashHistory. and set the mode as 'history'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using *createWeb**Hash**History* as mode your paths will be visited by prepending `#` to them like

```
/#bob
```

if you want to use a path like `/bob` you must use `createWebHistory` mode

Comment: oohf thanks man, is there any advantage to using this over the other?